# SwiftUI sheet presenting on tapping anywhere

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-button

I have created a `@StateObject` from where a Login page is presented:

```
@StateObject var loginViewModel = //LoginViewModel Name
```

and There is a Button inside Vstack like this

```
VStack{

Button(action : {loginViewModel.show.toggle()} )

{
HStack{
Text("Button")
}

}. sheet (isPresented : $loginViewModel.show){
//View (passing viewModel)
}

}
```

The problem is tappable area is now spread to the entire screen. That is I am getting the login view when tapping on all other elements (pretty much everywhere in the screen) in the screen instead of that button area.

Any solution for this and to confine that button action around that button only?

Comment: works well for me, on macos 12.3-beta, using xcode 13.3-beta, targets ios 15 and macCatalyst 12.
 Maybe it is due to some older OS version or some other code that you are not showing.

Comment: Try removing the HStack around the Text, it is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did to solve this issue was to Remove the Entire button and add an `onTapGesture` instead of that.

The reason I found for this was when there are multiple `ZStacks` in a view, touch event registering in one of them will be passed to all others which are currently in the view. Adjusting ZIndex was not helping. Also, I couldn't restrict touch on other areas because there were buttons on them too.

Eg:

```
HStack {
//Button Label Code
} .onTapGesture{

}//Button Action
```